# Jupyter Notebook : ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback

Tags: python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook in Windows 10 with Python 3.9.6. I have installed Jupyter Notebook with this command `pip install jupyter` and run it with this command `jupyter notebook`. So after starting the notebook, in the terminal I see some errors also but so far I don't seem to see any impact because of it. But still wanted to check, what that error actually indicates and is there a way to fix it?

```
[I 18:25:02.479 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb
[I 18:25:02.479 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.3 is running at:
[I 18:25:02.479 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=dfd2534b828985fcc116e9c400fd31381e9c8f19034e39d3
[I 18:25:02.479 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=dfd2534b828985fcc116e9c400fd31381e9c8f19034e39d3
[I 18:25:02.479 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:25:02.508 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/maryo/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-17088-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=dfd2534b828985fcc116e9c400fd31381e9c8f19034e39d3
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=dfd2534b828985fcc116e9c400fd31381e9c8f19034e39d3
c:\users\maryo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\encoder.py:257: UserWarning: date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
  return _iterencode(o, 0)
[W 18:27:49.960 NotebookApp] Notebook Covid Data Analysis.ipynb is not trusted
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x000002C98ECD81F0>()
handle: <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x000002C98ECD81F0>()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\maryo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-41' coro=<RequestHandler._execute() running at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py:1660> cb=[_HandlerDelegate.execute.<locals>.<lambda>() at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py:2326]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-40' coro=<MappingKernelManager.start_kernel() running at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py:176> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py:688]> is being executed.
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x000002C98DA94880>()
handle: <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x000002C98DA94880>()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\maryo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-30' coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py:840> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py:688]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-40' coro=<MappingKernelManager.start_kernel() running at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py:176> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py:688]> is being executed.
C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\ioloop\manager.py:9: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'RequestHandler._execute' was never awaited
  from .restarter import AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
ERROR:asyncio:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-41' coro=<RequestHandler._execute() running at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py:1660> cb=[_HandlerDelegate.execute.<locals>.<lambda>() at C:\Users\maryo\Desktop\python\jpnb\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py:2326]>
```

Comment: See [this github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6164) for explanations and fixes.

Answer (score 17):

On the bright side, this issue can be avoided by configuring Notebook to run with its AsyncMappingKernelManager instead - which introduces a full async stack

**This method is not a permanent method every time you open Jupyter notebook you need to add these settings**

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class=notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.AsyncMappingKernelManager
```

or

**This method is a permanent method**

Step 1

run

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

This will create jupyter_notebook_config.py in your Jupyter folder. The Jupyter folder is in your home directory, ~/.jupyter

Step 2

find these two lines in that folder

```
## The kernel manager class to use.
#  Default: 'notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.MappingKernelManager'
```

under that line **add this line**

```
c.NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class = 'notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.AsyncMappingKernelManager'
```

like this

```
## The kernel manager class to use.
#  Default: 'notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.MappingKernelManager'
#  c.NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class = 'notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.MappingKernelManager'
c.NotebookApp.kernel_manager_class = 'notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.AsyncMappingKernelManager'
```

*Save and run jupyter notebook as normal*

Comment: If you get `The 'kernel_manager_class' trait of <notebook.notebookapp.NotebookApp object at 0x7f0a210acc88> instance must be a type, but 'notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.AsyncMappingKernelManager' could not be imported`, make sure you've installed jupyter within the environment you're trying to launch a notebook from.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved my problem, struggled with that whole day

Answer (score 4):

The suggested fix by [Dumidu Parmith answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69819083/7403431) does not work for me due to

```sh
The 'kernel_manager_class' trait of <notebook.notebookapp.NotebookApp object at 0x7f0a210acc88> instance must be a type, but 'notebook.services.kernels.kernelmanager.AsyncMappingKernelManager' could not be imported
```

as mentioned in the comments to his answer.

As mentioned in the corresponding [github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6164) installing `jupyter_client<7` solved the issue for me.

So in case of conda, do

```
conda install 'jupyter_client<7'
```

and no configuration change is required. This installed version `6.1.2` in my case.

Comment: If one has the `jupyter-console` package installed, there will be a dependency conflict after downgrading `jupyter-client`. Above `jupyter-console==6.4.2`, `jupyter-console` requires `jupyter-client>=7.0.0`. So first, one has to downgrade to `jupyter-console==6.4.2` and then downgrade to `jupyter-client<7.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

if you using anaconda, you try "pip install jupyter", instead of "conda install jupyter".